# What is LaunchService in the startup apps of a relatively clean Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I just reinstalled my Windows 10 computer and I'm re-installing the bare minimum of apps I need to work and I found a few startup apps that I don't know what they are. What is LaunchService?

[image]

Comment: Can you check the Startup list in Task Manager? If it's there as well you may more easily find details about it (since it may show you the path and more), you may need to add additional columns with info to the view to see all the details.

Comment: @YisroelTech thank you. That was helpful to find out what other things in there are, since it allows to open the file location.

Answer (score 1):

This is the launcher for the CrashPlan engine as can be [seen on their manual](https://support.crashplan.com/hc/en-us/articles/8858137999629-Stop-and-start-the-CrashPlan-app-service-CrashPlan-for-Small-Business-#Windows%20per%20user%20installation%20(for%20me%20only):%7E:text=Paste%20the%20following%20into%20the%C2%A0Open%C2%A0dialog%2C%20or%C2%A0Browse%C2%A0to%20this%20location%2C%20replacing%20%3Cusername%3E%20with%20your%20Windows%20user%20name%3AC%3A%5CUsers%5C%3Cusername%3E%5CAppData%5CLocal%5CPrograms%5CCrashPlan%5CLaunchService.vbs):

[image]

I also independently confirmed it by turning it on and off and noticing whether CrashPlan worked or not after reboot. This is there only when CrashPlan is installed in single-user mode, which is necessary for encrypted hard drives.